# How can I use this multiselect dropdown twice on one page so each instance outputs to its own array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place two separate multiselct dropdown menus on one page for a form I am designing.

I found this lovely dropdown with checkboxes that I would like to use:

https://codepen.io/bseth99/pen/fboKH

I am trying to figure out the best way to run two instances of this dropdown on the same page, so that each dropdown's selections are saved in their own array.

```
var options = [];

$( '.dropdown-menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }

   $( event.target ).blur();

   console.log( options );
   return false;
});
```

Right now, if I place two instances of the button's HTML on my page, both dropdowns will modify the same "options" array because it's using a class selector for dropdown-menu. I know I can  use an ID selector instead of a class selector, and then just use the same block of jQuery over again with a different array, but is that really the best way to do this? I am new to jQuery but that seems bloated.

Comment: Create a jQuery plugin that wraps the code you have. [jQuery has a tutorial on how to do it](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.dropdown-menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

   var $target = $( this ),
       val = $target.data( 'value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   var options = $target.closest('.dropdown-menu').data('options') || [];


   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }

   $target.closest('.dropdown-menu').data('options', options);

   $( event.target ).blur();

   return false;
});

console.log($( '.dropdown-menu:eq(0)' ).data('options'));
```